# TFS build action - run my template edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, edmx

I have a solution with some projects in it. I would like to run my template (.tt) to refresh my .edmx every time that a check in (TFS) happens with changes on domain project.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.